# How to refresh curses window correctly?

Tags: python, refresh, ncurses, curses

```
while 1:
    ...
    window.addstr(0, 0, 'abcd')
    window.refresh()
    ...
```

`window` size is full terminal size, big enough to hold `abcd`.
If `'abcd'` is modified to shorter string like `'xyz'`, then on terminal I will see `'xyzd'`. What exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[addstr()](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr) only prints the string you specify, it does not clear the following characters. You will have to do that yourself:

- To clear characters until the end of the line, use [clrtoeol()](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.window.clrtoeol),
- To clear characters until the end of the window, use [clrtobot()](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.window.clrtobot).

Comment: Before `refresh()` and after `addstr()` (all these operations only update the "virtual" curses screen until `refresh()` is called).

Answer (score 19):

Let's suppose you have this code, and you just want to know how to implement `draw()`:

```
def draw(window, string):
    window.addstr(0, 0, string)
    window.refresh()

draw(window, 'abcd')
draw(window, 'xyz')  # oops! prints "xyzd"!
```

The most straightforward and "curses-ish" solution is definitely

```
def draw(window, string):
    window.erase()  # erase the old contents of the window
    window.addstr(0, 0, string)
    window.refresh()
```

You might be tempted to write this instead:

```
def draw(window, string):
    window.clear()  # zap the whole screen
    window.addstr(0, 0, string)
    window.refresh()
```

But don't! Despite the friendly-looking name, `clear()` is really only for [when you want the entire screen to get redrawn unconditionally,](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2014-01/msg00007.html) i.e., "flicker". The `erase()` function does the right thing without flicker.

Frédéric Hamidi offers the following solutions for erasing just part(s) of the current window:

```
def draw(window, string):
    window.addstr(0, 0, string)
    window.clrtoeol()  # clear the rest of the line
    window.refresh()

def draw(window, string):
    window.addstr(0, 0, string)
    window.clrtobot()  # clear the rest of the line AND the lines below this line
    window.refresh()
```

A shorter and pure-Python alternative would be

```
def draw(window, string):
    window.addstr(0, 0, '%-10s' % string)  # overwrite the old stuff with spaces
    window.refresh()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking how to remove the flicker and your answer was spot on!

Answer (score 1):

I use `oScreen.erase()`. It clears the window and puts the cursor back at 0,0